# React native app firebase crash report on splashscreen

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, react-native, splash-screen

Getting this crash quite often on firebase crashlytics.

Versions I'm consuming in my project:

"react": "16.8.6",

"react-native": "0.60.5",

"react-native-splash-screen": "3.2.0",

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

org.devio.rn.splashscreen.f

com.facebook.react.PackageList.getPackages (PackageList.java)
com.ingoibibo.MainApplication$1.getPackages (MainApplication.java)
com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.createReactInstanceManager (ReactNativeHost.java)
com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.getReactInstanceManager (ReactNativeHost.java)
com.facebook.react.HeadlessJsTaskService.access$000 (HeadlessJsTaskService.java)
com.facebook.react.HeadlessJsTaskService.onStartCommand (HeadlessJsTaskService.java)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs (ActivityThread.java:2983)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200 (ActivityThread.java:172)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1405)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:146)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5653)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1291)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1107)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java)
```

Unable to understand the cause of it. Let me know if anybody can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having same crash only for Android 4.4.X and enabling multidex fixed it.

You can follow following steps-

Step 1-
build.gradle (app)

```
defaultConfig {
  ...
  multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Step 2-
build.gradle (app)

```
dependencies {
  ...
  implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0"
}
```

Step 3-
MainApplication.java

```
import androidx.multidex.MultiDex;

public void onCreate() {
  ...
  MultiDex.install(this);
}
```